# PhpStorm 2019.2 doesn't reopen files after quitting

Tags: ide, phpstorm

My problem is quite simple,

Somehow, now whenever I reopen PhpStorm, it doesn't load back the open files from before quitting.

What's the configuration to get it fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself,

I deleted the **.idea/** folder and now it got back to normal